# Nested object no saving in firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

So I have this firebase object in my code that I am trying to save:

```
{"Education/schoolName": "RIT", 
"Education/major": "Computer Science", 
"Education/startYear": "November 25, 2015", 
"Education/endYear": "November 30, 2015"}
```

I got this error when trying to run my code:

```
Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument  contains an invalid key ("Education/schoolName") in property 'users.235642888'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"
at Error (native)
at https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:129:18
at hb (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:20:550)
at Sf (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:128:424)
at Rf (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:127:408)
at Tf (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:130:245)
at U.update (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:245:369)
at http://localhost:63342/startupadda/build/src/common/userData.js:59:32
at new Q (http://localhost:63342/startupadda/build/vendor/angular/angular.js:13491:5)
at Q (http://localhost:63342/startupadda/build/vendor/angular/angular.js:13478:14)
```

My angular service looks like this:

```
function saveUserDetails(email,object){
        var hashedEmail = Utilities.getHashCode(email);
        object = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(object));
        object = Utilities.flattenObject(object,{});
        var userRef = ref.child(hashedEmail);

        console.log("Saving object ",object);
        return $q(function(resolve,reject){
            return userRef.update(object, function(error){
                if(error){
                    reject(error);
                }else{
                    resolve("Updated successfully!");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

But when I try doing the same thing in my chrome console:

```
ref.update({"Education/schoolName": "RIT", 
"Education/major": "Computer Science", 
"Education/startYear": "November 25, 2015", 
"Education/endYear": "November 30, 2015"});
```

The object gets saved successfully in firebase. I don't know why this is not successful through my code since the object remains the same in both cases.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @DavidEast can you take a look at this? Thanks!

Comment: did you read the update error 'First argument  contains an invalid key'? - try to exclude '/' from you items key names, try: not "Education/schoolName", but "Education-schoolName" etc

Comment: @shershen If OP really want it in there, he can also escape it

Comment: @Mikey sure, that was next step. eliminating was just faster to explain to test

Comment: @shershen no problem, I was just making OP aware of it

Comment: Hi guys, basically I need this because I have a generic function that should work for both single level objects as well as nested objects. In either case, I don't understand if that object can be created successfully via console, why should it result into error from my code?

Comment: When you use the chrome console and save the object to firebase does it look identical in firebase?  If you look in the forge do the keys actually contain the forward slashes?

Comment: @Anid Monsur's answer should help.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an outdated version of Firebase's client library that does not support deep path updates. The latest version as of today, 11/21/2015 is 2.3.2.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html